# How can i design UserAccountsDrawerHeader in including safe area

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Here is an issue when I design drawer header using UserAccountsDrawerHeader, there is white space on the safe area in iPhone x and above model

as you can see in code I have used  UserAccountsDrawerHeader in the drawer widget

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: Text("Sidebar Demo"),
        elevation: defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android ? 5.0 : 0.0,
      ),
      drawer: new Drawer(
        child: new ListView(
          children: <Widget>[

            new UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                accountName: Text("Vijay Parmar"),
                accountEmail: Text("test@gmail.com"),
               currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
                 backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                  child: Text("V"),
               ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: new Text("Home"),
              trailing: Icon(Icons.home),
            ),

          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: new Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Text("Home"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Here is Drawer how looks]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
child: new ListView(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0),
  children: <Widget>[
```